# Using vbNull to insert NULL into a sql server database table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to insert text **MALE** or **FEMALE** into a table depending upon the user's input.

I used to following code to insert but the code inserts value **1** if none **(Male/Female)** selected.

```
query = "INSERT INTO student_profile_table(gender) VALUES(@gender)"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)

If rbtmale.Checked = True Then
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Male")
ElseIf rbtfemale.Checked = True Then
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Female")
Else
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", vbNull)
End If

con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Need some suggestions/corrections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you want `System.DbNull.Value` instead of `vbNull`.

`System.DbNull.Value` is the constant that SQL Server understands as null.

`vbNull` is intended to indicate if a Variant type is null.

Answer (score 0):

I've search in the net but I got no answer. What I did is I've used a blank image (totally white image) stored as default picture if no picture will be saved. Hoping this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way to make set with NULL value.

```
 If yourVariable Is Nothing Then
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detalleDesc", DBNull.Value)
Else
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detalleDesc", yourVariable )
End If
```

Regards